# Using Joda Time with IATA Time zone

Tags: java, timezone, jodatime, dst

Innovata publish the [IATA Time Zone/Daylight Saving Time](http://www.innovata-llc.com/data/data.html) data for airline industry.
These files contains airport code, [IATA Time Zone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IATA_code#IATA_timezone_codes), start/stop date for UTC offset, UTC offset and longitude/latitude for the airport.

What is the best practice to convert an [IATA Time Zone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IATA_code#IATA_timezone_codes) into [Olson Db/Tz Database format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) or [DateTimeZone for use with Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html)?

Comment: Do you have any more information about the format of these files?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I think it is possible to get sample files from Innovata. They are text files with offset from UTC, IATA Timezone code (country code + number/letter), latitude/longitude. (mail info@innovata-llc.com)

Comment: But presumably with dates for changes as well... can you use DateTimeZoneBuilder easily? (Were you aware of that before?)

Comment: Yes date and time for changes.

Comment: What do you need to do with the DateTimeZone after you have it?  In particular, do you need to just use if for computation, or do you need to output a name for it too?  Also, the input includes "start/stop date for UTC offset" - does this mean multiple records for a given airport, one for each DST/ST year-part in the schedule?

Comment: @Ed Staub: 1. Yes, multiple records for given airport and 2.yes, use it for computation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already added in a comment, but...

I suspect it would be easiest to just parse the file and create `DateTimeZone` instances via [`DateTimeZoneBuilder`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/tz/DateTimeZoneBuilder.html). You could also potentially implement [`ZoneInfoProvider`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/tz/ZoneInfoProvider.html) if you didn't want to pass the zones around.

Comment: DateTimeZoneBuilder could do the job, but it is a lot of work to map from IATA time zone codes to DateTimeZone codes.

Comment: @Kb: Really? If the IATA file gives you the ID, offsets and dates/times of changes, I can't see how it would be very much work.

Comment: The ID is not the Olson db/TZ Database ID. Offsets/dates/tmes are given. The job is to map olson db style ID to IATA style ID (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IATA_code#IATA_timezone_codes), or maybe I am just lazy. ;))

Comment: @Kb: That's not at all what you asked for though - you asked for a way of converting an IATA time zone into either a DateTimeZone or Olsen format. What I've proposed is a reasonably simple way of converting IATA time zone data into a DateTimeZone via DateTimeZoneBuilder. Joda Time doesn't *need* the ID to be a valid Olsen ID. If you just need to do arithmetic with the time zone, why don't you just use the DateTimeZoneBuilder, build a DateTimeZone and then use it?

Comment: Yes you are right and your answer is the closest to a solution. All I have to do now is to start mapping the IDs or YES just use the IATA IDs in Joda! ;))

Comment: @Kb: Sorry, I still don't understand why you need to map the IDs at all. Why not keep the IDs in the IATA format? You can ignore Olsen completely. As I mentioned, you could even build your own ZoneInfoProvider. The actual use of DateTimeZoneBuilder sounds like it should be reasonably simple. I think there may be some part of what you're doing which you haven't mentioned, otherwise I can't see where Olsen IDs come in...

Comment: Will do some coding experiments. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered converting the UTC offset to DateTimeZone instead?

Comment: Using factory method forOffsetHoursMinutes? I am not sure the Joda offset includes the DST?

Comment: Yes, and yes.  So you'd need to pick the right record, based on the start/stop date.  Then, because it has no rules, the DateTimeZone is what it is - there's effectively no concept of DST/no-DST; the offset is fixed.  Alternatively, sort all the records for an airport in start order and use them with DateTimeZoneBuilder.